# Find the axis of reflection which is described a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need help with the following example.

Find the axis of reflection which is described by a matrix $\frac{1}{10}\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
-1 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}$

Should I use eigenvectors because it was in the section about them?
Thank you for help.

Comment: The given matrix is orthogonal. If you normalize the column vectors you get a clockwise rotation by about $18.435°$ together with a compression by factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$.

Comment: I understand that if I take $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{E}$ so my matrix is orthonormal. So I try matrix for reflection. 
$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos^{-1}{(3/10)} & \sin^{-1}{(1/10)} \\
\sin^{-1}{(-1/10)} & \cos^{-1}{(-1/10)} \\
\end{pmatrix}$.
This gives me a matrix of different angles so what should I do now. Please can you clarify this for me? Thank you.

Comment: For a clockwise rotation, you need to find an angle $t$ such that
$$\frac 1{\sqrt{10}}\begin{pmatrix}  3 & -1 \\ 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}=  \begin{pmatrix}  \cos t & \sin t \\ -\sin t & \cos t\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: So, you matrix is not orthonormal but orthogonal.